# Values Disappear In Repeater when ADDING an empty row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, repeater

Actually i am trying to bind values in the repeater row and its also getting binded in a row,and i have gave them **ADD BUTTON** for adding additional rows to the repeater so that they can be flexible with working.But my problem is **AFTER FILLING THE FIRST ROW** when i press the **WHEN I PRESS THE ADD BUTTON**,all the values in the repeater gets disappear and a additional row is getting added.
I want the selected values in the row should be without disappear ,and an additional row should be added.
here is my code **FOR BINDING EMPTY ROW to repeater.**

```
{
 lstaddrow.Add(new IR_INVESTIGATION());
 rptinvest.DataSource = lstaddrow;
 rptinvest.DataBind();
}
```

here is my code **FOR EMPTY ROW.**

```
 List<IR_INVESTIGATION> lstEntered = new List<IR_INVESTIGATION>();
    using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext())
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptinvest.Items)
        {
            DropDownList ddlemployee = itm.FindControl("ddlemployee") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList ddlrole = itm.FindControl("ddlrole") as  DropDownList;
            TextBox email = itm.FindControl("email") as TextBox;
            TextBox depart = itm.FindControl("depart") as TextBox;
            TextBox pos = itm.FindControl("pos") as TextBox;
            IR_INVESTIGATION abKeyword = new IR_INVESTIGATION();
            lstEntered.Add(abKeyword);

        }

    }
    return lstEntered;
```

here is my code **BUTTON CLICK.**

```
        lstaddrow = addrows();
        rptinvest.DataSource = lstaddrow;
        rptinvest.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your repeater items are disappearing and then a single item appearing, because of these lines:

```
lstaddrow.Add(new IR_INVESTIGATION());
rptinvest.DataSource = lstaddrow;
rptinvest.DataBind();
```

This is creating a list of one item and then binding your repeater to it.

Instead, you want to add the new `IR_INVESTIGATION` object to the list of entered items (`lstEntered`) and only bind the repeater control to the `lstEntered` by making a call to this logic:

```
public List<IR_INVESTIGATION> AddRowToRepeater()
{
    List<IR_INVESTIGATION> lstEntered = new List<IR_INVESTIGATION>();
    using (EHSIMSDataContext db = new EHSIMSDataContext())
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptinvest.Items)
        {
            DropDownList ddlemployee = itm.FindControl("ddlemployee") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList ddlrole = itm.FindControl("ddlrole") as  DropDownList;
            TextBox email = itm.FindControl("email") as TextBox;
            TextBox depart = itm.FindControl("depart") as TextBox;
            TextBox pos = itm.FindControl("pos") as TextBox;
            IR_INVESTIGATION abKeyword = new IR_INVESTIGATION();
            lstEntered.Add(abKeyword);
        }
    }

    return lstEntered;
}
```

Now you can bind your repeater with the new row, like this:

```
rptinvest.DataSource = AddRowToRepeater();
rptinvest.DataBind();
```